# RETROPIE – Nintendo 64 + Keyboard troubles

Tags: raspberry-pi, emulation, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3, rom

I set keyboard inputs for Retropie at its Configuring window.(the keyboard will be the controller). It worked for SNES.

However, when I tried the N64 emulator, ***no key works*** (except the 'Esc' key). I would like the keyboard inputs that I set at Retropie to be the same for the N64 emulator.

However, I don't know how. May I have your helpful advice?

I thank you in advance :)